# Why Browsable attribute makes property not bindable?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, data-binding, bindingsource

I'm trying to use `System.Windows.Forms.PropertyGrid`.

To make a property not visible in this grid one should use `BrowsableAttribute` set to `false`.
But adding this attribute makes the property not bindable.

**Example:** Create a new Windows Forms project, and drop a `TextBox` and `PropertyGrid` onto `Form1`.  Using the code below, the width of the `TextBox` does not get bound to `Data.Width`:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Data data = new Data();
        data.Text = "qwe";
        data.Width = 500;

        BindingSource bindingSource = new BindingSource();
        bindingSource.Add(data);

        textBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", bindingSource, "Text", true,
            DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
        textBox1.DataBindings.Add("Width", bindingSource, "Width", true,
            DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);

        propertyGrid1.SelectedObject = data;
    }
}
```

The code for the data class is:

```
public class Data : IBindableComponent
{
    public event EventHandler TextChanged;
    private string _Text;
    [Browsable(true)]
    public string Text
    {
        get
        {
            return _Text;
        }
        set
        {
            _Text = value;
            if (TextChanged != null)
                TextChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }

    public event EventHandler WidthChanged;
    private int _Width;
    [Browsable(false)]
    public int Width
    {
        get
        {
            return _Width;
        }
        set
        {
            _Width = value;
            if (WidthChanged != null)
                WidthChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }

    #region IBindableComponent Members

    private BindingContext _BindingContext;
    public BindingContext BindingContext
    {
        get
        {
            if (_BindingContext == null)
                _BindingContext = new BindingContext();

            return _BindingContext;
        }
        set
        {
            _BindingContext = value;
        }
    }

    private ControlBindingsCollection _DataBindings;
    public ControlBindingsCollection DataBindings
    {
        get 
        {
            if (_DataBindings == null)
                _DataBindings = new ControlBindingsCollection(this);

            return _DataBindings;    
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region IComponent Members

    public event EventHandler Disposed;

    public System.ComponentModel.ISite Site
    {
        get
        {
            return null;
        }
        set
        {

        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region IDisposable Members

    public void Dispose()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

If you switch the Browsable attribute to true on every property in Data it works.
Now it seems like BindingSource searches datasource by Browsable Attribute.

Answer (score 6):

**Updated answer based on update example:**

I've done some digging in Reflector and discovered that the "problem" is actually in `ListBindingHelper`, which is used by `CurrencyManager`, which is in turn used by the `BindingSource` (these are all in the `System.Windows.Forms` namespace).

To discover the bindable properties, the `CurrencyManager` invokes `ListBindingSource.GetListItemProperties`.  Under the hood, this calls out to `GetListItemPropertiesByInstance` (when you pass in a single object).  That method has the following line of code at the end:

```
return TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(target, BrowsableAttributeList);
```

And the implementation of `BrowsableAttributeList` is:

```
private static Attribute[] BrowsableAttributeList
{
    get
    {
        if (browsableAttribute == null)
        {
            browsableAttribute = new Attribute[] { new BrowsableAttribute(true) };
        }
        return browsableAttribute;
    }
}
```

You can see that it is, in fact, filtering properties by `BrowsableAttribute(true)`.  It should probably be using `BindableAttribute` instead, but my guess is that the designers realized that everybody was already depending on `BrowsableAttribute` and decided to use that one instead.

So unfortunately you won't be able to get around this issue if you use `BrowsableAttribute`.  Your only options are to either do what Marc suggests and use a custom `TypeConverter`, or filter the property grid itself using one of the solutions in this question: [Programatically Hide Field in PropertyGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/626803/programatically-hide-field-in-propertygrid).

Comment: Yes, you are right. It seems to work. I have this problem in a larg project. I'll try to write a better example soon.

Answer (score 3):

`BrowsableAttribute` is used by a lot of the component-model way as a mechanism to avoid it being included. Perhaps the best option is to not add `[Browsable(false)]`.

There are several other ways of filtering `PropertyGrid`, including (in increasing complexity) `TypeConverter`, `ICustomTypeDescriptor`, `TypeDescriptionProvider` - but the simplest is probably to tell `PropertyGrid` the attributes that describe things you **do** want (`.BrowsableAttributes`), and mark the other properties.

Note that another option is to create a custom tab - but that is hit'n'miss in my experience.

Here's an example using `TypeConverter`, which is used by `PropertyGrid`, but not by most other bindings; it works by having a custom type-converter which excludes a specific property by name, but you could also use something like `Attribute.IsDefined` to do the masking:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.ComponentModel;
static class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Data data = new Data { Name = "the name", Value = "the value" };
        using (Form form = new Form
        {
            Controls =
            {
                new PropertyGrid {
                    Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
                    SelectedObject = data
                },
                new TextBox {
                    Dock = DockStyle.Bottom,
                    DataBindings = { {"Text", data, "Value"}, }
                },
                new TextBox {
                    Dock = DockStyle.Bottom,
                    DataBindings = { {"Text", data, "Name"}, }
                }
            }
        })
        {
            Application.Run(form);
        }        
    }
}
[TypeConverter(typeof(DataConverter))]
class Data
{
    class DataConverter : ExpandableObjectConverter
    {
        public override PropertyDescriptorCollection GetProperties(ITypeDescriptorContext context, object value, Attribute[] attributes)
        {
            var props = base.GetProperties(context, value, attributes);
            return new PropertyDescriptorCollection(
                (from PropertyDescriptor prop in props
                 where prop.Name != "Value"
                 select prop).ToArray(), true);
        }
    }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```