# ICustomTypeDescriptor throws argumentexception when implemented

Tags: c#, .net, propertygrid, icustomtypedescriptor

I want to exclude the Property MiddleName from the browseable Properties in my PropertyGrid.

When I hang around the interface ICustomTypeDescriptor on my Person class I get this exception while starting my app.

What do I wrong?

> System.ArgumentException:
>   Can not bind to the property or column TestNamefür on the DataSource.
>   Parametername: dataMember
>      bei System.Windows.Forms.BindToObject.CheckBinding()
>      bei System.Windows.Forms.Binding.SetListManager(BindingManagerBase bindingManagerBase)
>      bei System.Windows.Forms.ListManagerBindingsCollection.AddCore(Binding dataBinding)

```
public class Person : ICustomTypeDescriptor
{
    public string TestName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    AttributeCollection ICustomTypeDescriptor.GetAttributes()
    {
      return TypeDescriptor.GetAttributes(this, true);
    }
    string ICustomTypeDescriptor.GetClassName()
    {
      return TypeDescriptor.GetClassName(this, true);
    }
    string ICustomTypeDescriptor.GetComponentName()
    {
      return TypeDescriptor.GetComponentName(this, true);
    }
    TypeConverter ICustomTypeDescriptor.GetConverter()
    {
      return TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(this, true);
    }
    EventDescriptor ICustomTypeDescriptor.GetDefaultEvent()
    {
      return TypeDescriptor.GetDefaultEvent(this, true);
    }
    PropertyDescriptor ICustomTypeDescriptor.GetDefaultProperty()
    {
      return TypeDescriptor.GetDefaultProperty(this, true);
    }
    object ICustomTypeDescriptor.GetEditor(Type editorBaseType)
    {
      return TypeDescriptor.GetEditor(this, editorBaseType, true);
    }
    EventDescriptorCollection ICustomTypeDescriptor.GetEvents(Attribute[] attributes)
    {
      return TypeDescriptor.GetEvents(this, attributes, true);
    }
    EventDescriptorCollection ICustomTypeDescriptor.GetEvents()
    {
      return TypeDescriptor.GetEvents(this, true);
    }
    PropertyDescriptorCollection ICustomTypeDescriptor.GetProperties(Attribute[] attributes)
    {
      Debug.Print("GetProperties()");
      Print("Attributes is {0}null", attributes == null ? "" : "not ");
      PropertyDescriptorCollection origCol = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(this, attributes, true);
      bool wantBrowsable = attributes.Contains<Attribute>(new BrowsableAttribute(true));
      Debug.Print("Wants Browsable: {0}", wantBrowsable);
      List<PropertyDescriptor> newCol = new List<PropertyDescriptor>();
      foreach (PropertyDescriptor pd in origCol)
      {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("Property Name: {0}", pd.Name);
        if (pd.Name != "MiddleName")
        {
          System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("Property {0} is included.", pd.Name);
          newCol.Add(pd);
        }
      }
      return new PropertyDescriptorCollection(newCol.ToArray());
    }
    PropertyDescriptorCollection ICustomTypeDescriptor.GetProperties()
    {
      return ((ICustomTypeDescriptor)this).GetProperties(null);
    }
    object ICustomTypeDescriptor.GetPropertyOwner(PropertyDescriptor pd)
    {
      return this;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE + SOLUTION:**

Properties which are marked with `Browseable(false)` can not be bound! so I did this:

[Why Browsable attribute makes property not bindable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051337/why-browsable-attribute-makes-property-not-bindable)

The last solution from **Marc Gravell** worked like a breath!

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code seems to work in my test. Maybe we need more of your code to understand what's the problem.

Anyway, if your only purpose is just to hide `MiddleName` property from `Propertygrid`, why don't simply put `[Browsable(false)` attribute on that property, instead of implement an `ICustomTypeDescriptor`?

It would save you from a lot of code...

**EDIT:**

I mean, a code like this *must* work:

```
public class Person
{
    public string TestName { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Browsable(false)]
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

and should correctly hide `MiddleName` property from property grid...

Comment: I forgot to say => If I use the browseable attribut on TestName I get the same exception :/

Comment: Even if you remove the `ICustomTypeDescriptor` implementation from person class ? It seems really strange to me... Is Person class exactly how you posted it ?

Comment: @digEmAll Where did I say by implementing ICustomTypDescriptor that I do not want to have TestName as DataMember? Btw. this class is just a dummy class, I can not post the real code here.(not allowed)

Comment: Ok I found the error: an old DataBinding in a designer file but not used anymore. I removed the whole bindingsource and I got rid of the current exception. The Problem I see now is that my propertyGrid is bound to the person object and to some of its properties. The same time I have controls outside the propertygrid which are bound to the properties I want to hide in the propertygrid. Someone knows a solution for this?