# c# winforms property attributes and binding

Tags: c#, .net, binding, attributes

In order to get a more presentable list of properties to the end-user, I've added quite a lot of property attributes `DisplayName` and `Browsable(false)`.

Now, it appears the program crashes when trying to bind to the original property name (I didn't update all bindings). Follwoing error occurs:

```
System.ArgumentException: Cannot bind to the property or column MyPropertyName on the DataSource.
Parameter name: dataMember
   at System.Windows.Forms.BindToObject.CheckBinding()
   at System.Windows.Forms.BindToObject.SetBindingManagerBase(BindingManagerBase lManager)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Binding.SetListManager(BindingManagerBase bindingManagerBase)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ListManagerBindingsCollection.AddCore(Binding dataBinding)
   at System.Windows.Forms.BindingsCollection.Add(Binding binding)
   at System.Windows.Forms.BindingContext.UpdateBinding(BindingContext newBindingContext, Binding binding)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.UpdateBindings()
```

Is this a known behaviour, or am I looking at the wrong problem's origin?

Comment: Make sure you have a property with name (not display name)  `MyPropertyName` and it is not marked with `Browsable(false)`.

Comment: yep well, that's exactly the problem... It is marked as `Browsable(false)` because I don't want to see it in the property list... So no way around this, as far as I can tell??

Comment: No if you want to use it for data binding. `Browsable(false)` is removing it from the properties eligible for data binding.

Comment: Not sure what are you trying to achieve. Are you seeking for [`EditorBrowsableAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.editorbrowsableattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: @IvanStoev unfortunately this doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Ivan pointing me to the right direction.

Indeed `Browsable(false)` removes the property from `BindingSource` as explained in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051337/why-browsable-attribute-makes-property-not-bindable).

As I use DevExpress' property grid, it is sufficient to use an empty DisplayName to remove it from the list of showing properties in their components... So I simply added a `EmptyDisplayName` attribute which returns `null` as the DisplayName.

Note that I didn't check if this works for other property lists.