# Is it possible to view members other than public properties in a PropertyGrid?

Tags: c#, winforms, f#

Is it possible to view members other than public properties in a PropertyGrid? The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.propertygrid.aspx) says "all public properties of the SelectedObject will be displayed in the PropertyGrid *by default*". The "by default" seems to imply that it may be possible to view e.g. fields or non-public properties after some configuration.

Please note that I do not actually want to display anything other than public properties, I just need to know what it supports.

Comment: PropertyGrid is a pretty complicated control. Maybe you should ask what is you want to achieve with it. -1 not from me :)

Comment: I can't imagine _how_ it would see anything other than public members.  I think the "by default" doesn't refer to the "public" part of the statement, but rather the "all will be displayed" part.

Comment: @David - it could see non-public members via reflection same as public members.

Comment: @AseemGautam - I am creating a plugin architecture for my open source project FsEye (https://code.google.com/p/fseye/). The IPlugin interface has an `IsWatchable : Type -> bool` member which plugin authors can use to indicate whether an instance of a given type is watchable. One of the built-in plugins I'm developing is based on the PropertyGrid. So I want `IsWatchable` to return false if an instance of a given type doesn't have anything useful which can be displayed in a PropertyGrid.

Comment: @StephenSwensen: I don't think it's going to do that natively.  At least I hope it doesn't.  Non-public members are non-public for very good reasons.  In a polymorphic world, for all intents and purposes, non-public members don't exist external to the object.

Comment: @David - I suppose it depends on the context. During development it can be useful to examine and mutate non-public members.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So basically you want control over what is displayed inside a property grid. Yes that is possible.

An object may provide custom information about itself by implementing an interface `ICustomTypeDescriptor`. If this is not implemented, the static `TypeDescriptor` is used by the property grid.

So we need to implement [ICustomTypeDescriptor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.icustomtypedescriptor%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

The property information will be returned by the interface method [GetProperties()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/13s3dz2h.aspx). This method returns an object of type PropertyDescriptorCollection.

**Edit:** You should take a look at PropertyGrid.BrowsableAttributes for a simpler solution. [Programatically Hide Field in PropertyGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/626803/programatically-hide-field-in-propertygrid)

Some useful links -

[.NET Matters: ICustomTypeDescriptor, Part 1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163816.aspx)

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4448/Customized-display-of-collection-data-in-a-Propert

Comment: Please check edit for alternate solution. Better and simpler.

Comment: Thanks, this answers my question! Basically, `Type.GetProperties().Length > 0` is not sufficient for my `IsWatchable` implementation!